# Click on button image won't load

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

When I click on the button, my ImageView car disappears and nothing else shows up:

I have this view:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Background"
    android:layout_width="646dp"
    android:layout_height="313dp"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:contentDescription=""
    android:layout_marginRight="-111dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RtlHardcoded" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/wheel"
    android:layout_width="646dp"
    android:layout_height="313dp"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:contentDescription=""
    android:layout_marginRight="-111dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RtlHardcoded" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/car"
    android:layout_width="646dp"
    android:layout_height="313dp"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:contentDescription=""
    android:layout_marginRight="-111dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RtlHardcoded" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="113dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />
```

And this mainActivity:

```
ImageView background;
ImageView car;
ImageView wheel;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    background = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Background);
    wheel = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.wheel);
    car = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.car);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            image2();            }
    });

    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://i.imgur.com/OrletzA.png").into(background);
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://i.imgur.com/qfOQnLO.png").into(wheel);
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://i.imgur.com/AjvZ7vJ.png").into(car);
}

public void image2(){
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://i.imgur.com/OJ4XCYu.png").into(car);
}
```

I try using this method from Picasso to see if i have an error:

```
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).setLoggingEnabled(true);
```

But nothing.

Before Clicking
[image]

After Clicking
[image]

What can i do to fix it?

Comment: Anything in the logcat? Did you forget to declare the INTERNET permission in the Manifest?

Comment: Like you can see in the "Before click" and "after click" image in the question, I can see some images. but when I click on the button, my imageview "car" disappear and only show the background and wheel.

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong in your code as far as I know. Show your log. The images might be too big to load, and your memory is getting full. Try to resize or use smaller images. Also try with other small images to make sure the problem isn't with THESE images.

Comment: Can you try it with another (preferably smaller size) image?

Comment: i try with this link:

http://i.imgur.com/ZeX82L0.png

and got this log:

03-24 00:56:12.542 11802-11802/com.web.media.studio.acscomposite D/Picasso: Main        created      [R11] Request{http://i.imgur.com/ZeX82L0.png}

03-24 00:56:33.582 11802-11828/com.web.media.studio.acscomposite D/Picasso: Dispatcher  batched      [R11]+21s for error